# WordPress Divi site mobile menu not scrolling

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress site running an ET Divi child theme and on mobile the main menu does not scroll on touch, instead the background (website) scrolls. I've been trying several media queries and such to fix but cannot figure it out, anyone have thoughts or run into this before? Here is my child theme stylesheet add-on code:

the website is [wptemp.thereverendmichael.com](http://wptemp.thereverendmichael.com) (make sure to adjust width for mobile viewing only)

```
@media (max-width: 980px) {
#main-header {
position: fixed !important;
}
}

@media (max-width: 980px) {
.et_fixed_nav #top-header {
    position:fixed !important;
}
#mobile-menu {
    overflow-y:scroll!important;
    -overflow-scrolling:touch!important;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch!important;
}
}

.et_mobile_menu {
 margin-left: -30px;
 padding: 5%;
 width: calc( 100% + 60px);
}

.mobile_nav.opened .mobile_menu_bar:before {
 content: "\4d";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, I figured it out with a bit more playing. Here was the solution

EDIT: Future Divi versions have changed `.et-mobile-menu` to `.et_mobile_menu` just thought I'd give a heads up.

```
.et_mobile_menu {   
    overflow-y:scroll!important;
    max-height:80vh!important;
    -overflow-scrolling:touch!important;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch!important;
}
```

Comment: Who woulda thought 4 years later this is still relevant. Divi's mobile menu is a mess... Thanks!